# Sorting a list of Strings based on how a list of objects was sorted

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a problem, I was trying to sort a list of strings based on how a list of objects was sorted.

This is my code:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));

List<objects> items = List<objects>();
List<String> filteritems = List();

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {


  void berechnung() {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].result = items[i].number1 + items[i].number2;
    }
    final Map<String, String> mappings = {
      for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        items[i].title : filteritems[i]
    };
    Comparator<objects> sortById = (a, b) => a.result.compareTo(b.result);
    items.sort(sortById);

    filteritems = [
      for (objects item in items) mappings[item]
    ];

    print(filteritems);
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    items = [
      objects(title: 'Gummibärchen', number1: 1, number2: 3, result: 0),
      objects(title: 'Schokolade', number1: 5, number2: 2, result: 0),
      objects(title: 'Eis', number1: 4, number2: 6, result: 0),
      objects(title: 'Nutella', number1: 2, number2: 0, result: 0),
    ];
    filteritems = ['Gummibärchen','Schokolade','Eis','Nutella' ];
    berechnung();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Mapping'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(items[index].title),
                  Text(items[index].result.toString()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


class objects {
  String title;
  int number1;
  int number2;
  int result;

  objects({this.title,this.number1,this.number2,this.result});
}
```

I am very new to coding so i don't understand all the code I wrote that good, I just copied code and hopped for the best, but that didn't help me.
My Output of the Line `print(filteritems);` is [null, null, null, null], I was hoping to get:
[Nutella, Gummibärchen, Schokolade, Eis] because this is the way the other list was sorted.

I hope someone can help with this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You need to use `mappings[item.title]` not `mappings[item]`

```
filteritems = [for (objects item in items) mappings[item.title]];
```

output

```
I/flutter (20843): [Nutella, Gummibärchen, Schokolade, Eis]
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));

List<objects> items = List<objects>();
List<String> filteritems = List();

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  void berechnung() {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].result = items[i].number1 + items[i].number2;
    }
    print(items.toString());
    final Map<String, String> mappings = {
      for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) items[i].title: filteritems[i]
    };

    print(mappings.toString());
    Comparator<objects> sortById = (a, b) => a.result.compareTo(b.result);
    items.sort(sortById);

    print(items.toString());
    filteritems = [for (objects item in items) mappings[item.title]];

    print(filteritems);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    items = [
      objects(title: 'Gummibärchen', number1: 1, number2: 3, result: 0),
      objects(title: 'Schokolade', number1: 5, number2: 2, result: 0),
      objects(title: 'Eis', number1: 4, number2: 6, result: 0),
      objects(title: 'Nutella', number1: 2, number2: 0, result: 0),
    ];
    filteritems = ['Gummibärchen', 'Schokolade', 'Eis', 'Nutella'];
    berechnung();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Mapping'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(items[index].title),
                  Text(items[index].result.toString()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class objects {
  String title;
  int number1;
  int number2;
  int result;

  objects({this.title, this.number1, this.number2, this.result});
}
```